# Set of nilpotent elements in $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

An element $r\in R$ is called *nilpotent* if $r^n=0$ for some integer $n=1,2,\dots $.

We have the following:

- When $r$ is nilpotent then $1-r$ is invertible in $R$.
- If $R$ is commutative then the set $N(R)$ of nilpotent elements is an ideal of $R$. This is not true when the ring is not commutative.

> I want to show that $N(\mathbb{Z}_m)=0$ if and only if $m$ is not divisible by a square of a prime.

---

Suppose that $N(\mathbb{Z}_m)=0$, then  $r^n\neq 0$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, where $r\in \mathbb{Z}_m$, right?

How could we continue?

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive, i.e. if the square of a prime divides $m$ then $N(\mathbb{Z_m)} \neq 0$.

Comment: If the square of a prime, say $p$, divides $m$, we can take $r=\frac{m}{p}$, then $r^2=\frac{m^2}{p^2}=\frac{p^{2j}q_1^{i_1}\cdots q_n^{i_n}}{p^2}=p^{2j-2}q_1^{i_1}\cdots q_n^{i_n}$, right? Or is an other choice for $r$ better? @EthanAlwaise

Comment: Right. Put more simply, suppose $m = ap^2$ for some prime $p$. Then $(ap)^2 = am = 0$.

Comment: Then $ap\in N(\mathbb{Z}_m)$, so $N(\mathbb{Z}_m)\neq 0$. That proves the direction $\Rightarrow$ of the iff statement, or not? @EthanAlwaise

Comment: Correct, so now you just have to show that if $m$ is not divisible by the square of a prime, then $N(\mathbb{Z}_m) = 0$.

Comment: If $m$ is not divisible by the square of a prime then $m=ap^2+1$, right? Then $(ap)^2=a^2p^2=a(m-1)=am-a$. We have that this is equal to zero only when $a$ is a multiple of $m$, right? @EthanAlwaise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $m = ap^2 + 1$. That would imply that if $m$ is not divisible by the square of a prime, then $m - 1$ is. Consider $m = 2$.

If $m$ is not divisible by the square of a prime, then $m = p_1\ldots,p_t$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes. Suppose $a \in \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $a^n = 0$. Then $m$ divides $a^n$, hence each prime factor $p_i$ of $m$ divides $a$. But then $m$ divides $a$, so $a = 0$. Hence $N(\mathbb{Z}_m) = 0$.

Comment: Why does it follow that when $m$ divides $a$  then $a=0$ ?

Comment: I should have said let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $m$ divides $a$, then $a \equiv 0 \pmod m$, so $a = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)